# Bash in Terminal Vscode

Tags: python, windows, bash, terminal

I have a problem.I'm working on a project (creating notepad in python) and when i ended up my project code.I should run it in bash terminal but when I type `"python vpad.py"` it show me this:

> "C:\Users\Amirhoseyn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'vpad.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Please solve my problem

Comment: Are you running the command in same directory as `vpad.py`?

Comment: @Mohammad : The error message says that there is no name of this file in your working directory. To solve the problem, move or copy the file to your working directory.